# sqlite + java / java.sql.SQLException: no such column

Tags: java, select, sqlexception

I have a problem with querying a single column. Whereby it works when I query the whole table. Whats the problem?

```
I'm getting this error:

java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'Id'
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:54)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getInt(JDBC3ResultSet.java:406)
    at Application.DBStatement.showData(DBStatement.java:135)
    at Application.DBStatement.createQuery(DBStatement.java:121)
    at Application.DBStatement.search(DBStatement.java:179)
    at Main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:61)
```

//-----------------

```
try {
            dbStatement.search(1, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

//------------------

```
public void search(int number, String searchText) throws SQLException {
        
        String searchQuery= "";
        
        switch (number) {

        case 1:
            searchQuery = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_Name + " = " + "'" + searchText + "'";   // that isn't working
            
            //searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_Name + " = " + "'" + searchText + "'";   // that's working
            
        break;
        
        default:
            break;
        }           
    }
```

//-----------------------

```
public void createTable() throws SQLException {
    
        
        String createTable= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + 
                "( " 
                 + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                 + COLUMN_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                 + COLUMN_EMail + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                 + COLUMN_Registration_Date + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                
                + " )";     
    }
```

Comment: because of where-clause `COLUMN_Name` should be provided in selected columns

Comment: "no such column: 'Id'" => Well ... clear enough, isn't it?

Comment: Is there a line feed in there?

Comment: Thorbjørn : No, there isn't

Comment: Seelenvirtuose: I do have column Id: 

 private final String TABLE_NAME = "Users";
 
 private final String COLUMN_ID = "Id";
 private final String COLUMN_Name = "Name";
 private final String COLUMN_EMail = "EMail";
 private final String COLUMN_Registration_Date = "Registration";

Comment: anatoli: I added a name like this: try {
            dbStatement.search(1, "Helga");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

But it still fails :(